# How to reinject the packet in the Iptables?

Tags: iptables, routing, tunneling

I have a packet inside a packet a.k.a tunneling. So essentially it's of the following form: 
`[IP HEADER 1][IP HEADER 2][PAYLOAD]` 
 After reading the first header(done by a library) I will get the packet:
 `[IP HEADER 2][PAYLOAD]` 
at the INPUT chain of the iptables. I want to re-inject the packet to the starting of the iptables i.e. in the PREROUTING chain. Ultimate aim is to forward the packet to a remote host (that's why I want the packet to be in the PREROUTING chain). I have read something about the libipq but I am not really sure that it is the best way to do it. Any wild suggestion would also help.
I have already posted this question in 'stackoverflow' but since there were no replies, so I thought it is better suited for 'serverfault'.

Answer (score 3):

I agree with MrShunz's answer. Use [libnetfilter_queue](http://netfilter.org/projects/libnetfilter_queue/). To use it, you will need a Linux kernel version 2.6.14 or later built with nfnetlink_queue support. There are two parts to set up:

1. Your `iptables`/netfilter rules to send packets to user-land, and
2. your user-land program, which will process the packets as desired and then return them to netfilter.

The `iptables` rule might look something like this:

```
IN_INTERFACE=eth0
SOURCE_NETWORK=192.168.66.0/24
QUEUE_NUM=1
iptables -t raw -A PREROUTING -i $IN_INTERFACE -s $SOURCE_NETWORK -j NFQUEUE --queue-num $QUEUE_NUM
```

This will send all packets coming in through a specific interface from a specific network to your user-land process that is listening on queue number 1.

Your program, which will likely have to be written in C or C++, will use the [libnetfilter_queue API](http://www.netfilter.org/projects/libnetfilter_queue/doxygen/). Sorry, I'm not going to write any code here (there is example code in the API docs I linked to), but the basic idea is that your program will:

- read each packet sent to the queue,
- make your desired modifications to the packet,
- and finally, specify a "verdict" to netfilter, saying whether to ACCEPT or DROP the packet. Presumably, you will be ACCEPTing most of the time.

I have not personally used this API, but my reading of the docs is that ACCEPTing a packet actually means to reinject it, as modified, back into netfilter, to continue traversing the `iptables` rulesets. I could be wrong on this point, so you may want to investigate further before committing to this course of development.

Answer (score 1):

IIRC, to reinject (to the start of the chain, though!), use `NF_REPEAT` as a verdict.

Comment: thanks.. btw, where did you find it? It's not even mentioned in the man pages.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like libipq has been *deprecated* by [libnetfilter_queue](http://www.netfilter.org/projects/libnetfilter_queue/index.html). The documentation states:

> issuing verdicts and/or **reinjecting** altered packets to the kernel nfnetlink_queue subsystem

seems like what you're looking for...

Comment: Even after using 'libnetfilter_queue'/'libipq'.. I am not able to figure out the mechanism as to how the packet could be transfered to PREROUTING chain. Could you please help me in this regard?

Comment: @Amit Sorry, just found it with a little bit of googling. Never used.

Comment: no problem. :)